# Are the sentences "My farm was mostly livestock. I really enjoyed helping out with them." correct (not proofreading)?

Tags: exam-questions, ielts

I have some doubts about these sentences:

> My farm was mostly livestock. I really enjoyed helping out with them.

Is it better to say "Something on my farm are mostly livestock"? I feel a little bit weird about the expression "farm is mostly livestock". It's just like saying "house is mostly people".

The sentences come from a listening material of IELTS.

Comment: That's two sentences. Did you write them, or someone else?

Comment: On this site, we cannot ask for proofreading "Is this sentence correct" is a request for proofreading. Also, you're asking two questions in one, which we can't do on this site. If you really want to ask it, you can ask a new question and ask there.

Comment: I don't see this as proofreading,  A specific concern has been identified:  The use of "was" in "My farm was mostly livestock" reopen.

Answer (score 1):

This is rather unclear speech, but not untypical of the kind of fumbled sense that is common in unrehearsed speech.

There is a word (an adjective) "arable" to describe a farm that has crops. Non-arable farms are sometimes described as "livestock farms" using the attributive noun "livestock".  Here the speaker has incorrectly used the noun "livestock" as an adjective.

So this is an error.  But the meaning is clear.  The farm was a pastoral farm and the speaker enjoyed helping out with care for the animals.

Answer (score 0):

***My farm was mostly livestock*** and I enjoyed helping out with **it**. [singular, uncountable noun]

The house was filled with ***people*** and I enjoyed meeting ***them***. [plural noun]

However, if the farm is yours are you only helping out other people on it?